# How to dispose StreamReader and StreamWriter on the same memory stream?

Tags: c#, stream

```
 class StreamReaderWriterDemo : AbastractDemo
{
    public override void Run()
    {
        string message = "hello this is a test 0000";

        string result = string.Empty;

        try
        {
            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(memoryStream, Encoding.Default);
                this.WriteToStream(streamWriter, memoryStream, message);
                memoryStream.Position = 0;

                StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(memoryStream, Encoding.Default);

                result = this.ReadFromStream(streamReader, memoryStream);


                streamWriter.Dispose();
                streamReader.Dispose();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }

        Console.WriteLine(result);          
    }


    private void WriteToStream(StreamWriter streamWriter, MemoryStream stream, string message)
    {
            streamWriter.Write(message);
            streamWriter.Flush();
            streamWriter.Close();
    }

    private string ReadFromStream(StreamReader streamReader, MemoryStream stream)
    {
        string result;

            result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();

        return result;
    }
}
```

> I have trouble to dispose the streamReader reader, because the streamWriter.Dsipose() already disposed the memoryStream.

So I am kind of confused, does it imply I don't have to dispose the StreamReader or streamWriter?

What is correct way to dispose the StreamWriter, StreamReader that use the same memory stream?

Please give me some advices?

Comment: Why do you think there's something wrong with disposing both of them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In reality, nothing horrible will happen because neither `MemoryStream` nor `StreamReader`/`StreamWriter` do anything fancy in their `Dispose()` methods (this can be verified with something like .NET Reflector). But you should not assume this.

For correctness, *any and all* objects of types that implement `IDisposable` should be disposed. The best way to do this is with the `using` construct, which you used in your example. But you should also use it for the readers and writers, not just the memory stream:

```
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(memoryStream, Encoding.Default))
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(memoryStream, Encoding.Default))
{
    this.WriteToStream(streamWriter, memoryStream, message);
    memoryStream.Position = 0;


    result = this.ReadFromStream(streamReader, memoryStream);
}
```

There is nothing wrong with disposing all 3 objects, even though two of them "wrap" the third. (In fact, you're *supposed* to do so.)

If you want to be able to continue to use the memory stream after you dispose the reader/writer, the `StreamReader` class [has a constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg712952%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which takes a flag telling it to leave the underlying stream open after the reader is disposed. There is a similar constructor for `StreamWriter`.

Comment: If you put the `StreamReader` in `using` and use a `FileStream`, you get an exception on `StreamWriter` disposal - this seems to contradict your statement about always disposing.

Comment: This will generate CA2202 warning

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
class StreamReaderWriterDemo
{
    public void Run()
    {
        string message = "hello this is a test 0000";

        string result = string.Empty;

        try
        {
            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(memoryStream, Encoding.Default))
            {
                WriteToStream(streamWriter, memoryStream, message);
                memoryStream.Position = 0;

                var streamReader = new StreamReader(memoryStream, Encoding.Default);

                result = this.ReadFromStream(streamReader, memoryStream);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }


    private void WriteToStream(StreamWriter streamWriter, MemoryStream stream, string message)
    {
        streamWriter.Write(message);
        streamWriter.Flush();
    }

    private string ReadFromStream(StreamReader streamReader, MemoryStream stream)
    {
        string result;

        result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();

        return result;
    }
}
```

As other answers have mentioned, the dispose statement is being called by the using construct. You were also closing the stream prior to closing the writer inside the WriteToStream member.

Comment: You aren't disposing of `StreamReader` - if you put the `StreamReader` in `using`, you get an exception on the `StreamWriter` disposal with a `FileStream`.